# Admin-On-Rest auto logout after timeout

Tags: reactjs, redux, admin-on-rest

I would like the user to be automatically logged out, when the expiration time of his auth-token has come. How would I dispatch a logout action, without having access to the store (and therefore the dispatch function)?
I feel like wrapping every view component with a timeout component which then dispatches the logout seems over the top.

As i understand from [issue 229](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/issues/229) and [issue 574](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/pull/574) on github there is no clean way to access the dispatch function from the redux store of AOR while *not* being in a component.

How would I achieve an automatic logout (with store clearance, as the logout action does)?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a custom saga, see the [doc](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Admin.html#customsagas).

```
// in logoutIfTokenExpiredSaga.js
import { call, put, takeEvery } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { userLogout } from 'admin-on-rest';

function getUserToken() {
    return localStorage.getItem('token');
}

function hasTokenExpired(token) {
    // Write your custom logic for token expiration check
}

function* autoLogout() {
    const token = yield call(getUserToken);
    const hasExpired = yield call(hasTokenExpired);

    if (hasExpired) {
        yield put(userLogout());
    }
}

export default function* logoutIfTokenExpiredSaga() {
    yield takeEvery('AOR/USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS', autoLogout);
}
```